# Floating point number calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to working with bitcoin and I made a javascript that adds 10 satoshi every second and then it displays on the screen in BTC.

Can someone show me why it starts showing strange numbers and then the decimal points are incorrect? I need it to start with 0.00000010 BTC

```js
var start = 0;
window.setInterval(
  function() {
    start = start + 10;
    var btc = start / 100000000;

    console.log(btc + " BTC");
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what goes wrong. How is the decimal point incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toFixed()` method will do the trick in this case, and you will also have to increment with `0.00000010` if you want it to start from that. See the working snippet below please:

```js
var start = 0;
window.setInterval(
  function() {
    start = start + 0.00000010;
    var btc = start.toFixed(8);

    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = btc + " BTC";
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id='start'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `toFixed()` you get the results:-)

```js
var start = 0 ;
window.setInterval(function () {
    start = start + 10;
    var btc = parseFloat(start / 100000000).toFixed(8);
    console.log(btc + " BTC");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Please do not copy the answer from me

Comment: @lonut I am not copy your answer.. Kindly see my edited history

Comment: Yes, you did. Your code didn't even worked as OP wanted until you added `toFixed()` from my answer. I think anyone can see that from the edit history. You had an entire different explanation and code. You used `btc.toPrecision(8) + " BTC";`, which did not work.

Comment: I not copy.. Please contact admin and check the all history with time. Yes initially using that, after that i try another answer...

Comment: You tried that because you've seen that my answer worked. Your snippet wasn't even runnable at first and didn't worked. So please be fair. It'a a matter of principles man. Grow up. The truth is in your edit history. I will stop here commenting because I consider it will be useless and unhelpul to anyone else. I've said my point.

Comment: Hey man.. you think that you only know something.. Other one dont think same that .. According to my It's my own thinking not copied.. If you felt anything, then surely i will delete my post.. But one thing, dont think that some one thing same... Shall I delete my post?